# Sorting in MySQL using a CASE expression shows results I don't understand

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I'm building a small program that allows teachers to create exams from a bank of questions. The teacher can then sort the questions in the order that he/she would like them to appear on the exam.

So I am trying to return a list of questions based on the order of record ID's.

```
SELECT * FROM ExamQuestion WHERE ElementID = 66
```

returned the following results...

```
2505
2506
2615
2616
2617
```

If I then try to sort these results based on the question order the teacher sets using the query below...

```
SELECT * FROM ExamQuestion WHERE ElementID = 66 ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN ID = '2616' THEN '1'
    WHEN ID = '2615' THEN '2'
    WHEN ID = '2617' THEN '3'
    WHEN ID = '2505' THEN '4'
    ELSE ID END ASC
```

I get the following results

```
2616
2615
2506
2617
2505
```

This is almost perfect but what I can't work out is why 2506 is being returned before 2617 even though it is explicitly set.

Normally in this query I won't have a full list of ID's, it will vary depending on what questions the teacher would like to ask on the exam...

I would have thought that 2506 should appear last in the list...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Case EXPRESSION, not case statement.

Comment: @jarlh, yes, agreed & done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your `CASE` statement:

```
CASE 
    WHEN ID = '2616' THEN '1'
    WHEN ID = '2615' THEN '2'
    WHEN ID = '2617' THEN '3'
    WHEN ID = '2505' THEN '4'
    ELSE ID END ASC
```

The value `'2506'` falls into the `ELSE` condition, which will sort by the `ID` value itself.  In this case, the value is `'2506'`, which falls in between the strings `'2'` and `'3'`.

Here is your result set next to which I list the values which were actually used to sort the results:

```
+------+------------+
|  ID  | Sort Value |
+------+------------+
| 2616 |   '1'      |
| 2615 |   '2'      |
| 2506 |   '2506'   |    <-- '2506' is in between '2' and '3'
| 2617 |   '3'      |
| 2505 |   '4'      |
+------+------------+
```

Comment: @Colin: remember that they are ordered as strings, not integers. Hence, Tim's explanation is spot on.

Comment: Is that because '2506' is a string, whereas 2506 is a number? Would Colin's query work if he simply removed the quotes around all the integers that make them strings?

Comment: I would assume ID is an integer column, so there is no reason to treat 1,2,3,4 etc as anything else than integer in the `case expression`. It should then work.... unless ID is a string data type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys - you were all spot on... The ordering was indeed done as a string. If I turn the THEN section of the CASE statement into numeric (remove the quotes around the number) then it works as I would expect

```
SELECT * FROM MightyMindsExamQuestion WHERE IFElementID = 66 ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN ID = '2616' THEN 1
    WHEN ID = '2615' THEN 2
    WHEN ID = '2617' THEN 3
    WHEN ID = '2505' THEN 4
ELSE ID END ASC
```

Results

```
2616
2615
2617
2505
2506
```

Thanks for your help...